# Mongo Case Insensitive index (collation) not getting results

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm trying to use the CaseInsensitive Index using Mongoid 5. I even went down to the Mongo console to run the experiments but it won't pull the results at all:

```
> db.charges.getIndexes()
[
  {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
      "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "paymentsapi_development.charges"
  }
]
> db.charges.createIndex({'details.email':1},{name:'emails_index',collation:{locale:'en',strength:1}})
{
  "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
  "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
  "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
  "ok" : 1
}
> db.charges.getIndexes()
[
  {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
      "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "paymentsapi_development.charges"
  },
  {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
      "details.email" : 1
    },
    "name" : "emails_index",
    "ns" : "paymentsapi_development.charges",
    "collation" : {
      "locale" : "en",
      "strength" : 1
    }
  }
]
> db.charges.find({'details.email':'lolo@lolo.com'}).count()
1
> db.charges.find({'details.email':'LoLo@LoLo.cOm'}).collation({locale:'en',strength:1}).count()
0
>
```

I'm basing in the Collation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) and the Case Insensitive Index (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/) .

I already checked the db version, the `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: <version> } )` based on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/ and all further things possible.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Those are "version 1" indexes. And they need to be `v: 2`. MongoDB version from `db.version()`? And check that you don't have a [`setFeatureCompatibilityVersion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) to anything lower than 3.4. I know you said you did it, but please do it again.

Comment: Thanks Neil.. My `db.version()` is `3.0.15-6-g55552c7`, and my mongod version says database version is 3.4.10. The thing I don't get is the v1 indexes. I understand that those are actually 3.4 new features.

Comment: No dude. `db.version()` actually tells you what the "database" version is, not the "shell". That's why I asked. So you actually do not have 3.4. You are possibly confused with the "shell" startup message, which reports it's own version. But the actual server version confirms it. So these are V1 indexes, and that's evidenced not only by the version but also a load of extra options that actually appear under `collation` on a 3.4 instance. It sticks the "metadata" on the index without error, but you cannot use it without a supporting version.

Comment: `3.0.x` is actually no longer officially supported. So it's really time to upgrade anyway. You need `3.4` to support collation features, just like is documented.

Comment: Thanks man. That was something to do with local mongo conflicts. I made it work smoothly with Docker. Now how can I prevent this question from polluting StackOverflow? lol